# Composing and selecting Data from odata Output in Flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, power-automate, flow, microsoft-graph

I have used Power automate flow to return O365 group owners using Graph API. It has returned data in @odata.context. From that output I need only "Email" field so I can send it to Powerapps in a table format.

After I get output from Graph API I am using compose operation and after that select operation to get Email field of users.

But in compose operation not sure what expression to use in order to compose the data. Can you guide?

Comment: Can you show us the format of output/response you are getting? Based on that we can suggest the expression to use.

Comment: {
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#directoryObjects",
  "value": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
      "id": "123",
      "businessPhones": [
        "82"
      ],
      "displayName": "abc",
      "givenName": "xyz",
      "jobTitle": "acb",
      "mail": "Email",
      "mobilePhone": null,
      "officeLocation": "OFFICES",
      "preferredLanguage": null,
      "surname": "bc",
      "userPrincipalName": "UPN mail"
]
    },
    }

Comment: Check my answer given below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly use output from your Graph API call in **Select** action without using Compose action.

Use Power automate flow like this:

[image]

**Expressions used**:

**From** property:

```
body('HTTP')?['value']
```

Here, instead of `body('HTTP')`, you can write name/output of your actual Graph API action.

**Map property**: Right hand side expression for Email

```
@item()?['mail']
```

**Output**: Email addresses in table/array of objects format

[image]